# How to read public variable from contract using ethers.js

Tags: solidity, dapps, dapp-development, ethers.js

I am trying to read public variable from contract on chain using ethers.js.

Calling the methods work but I could not manage to read public property (without getter).

The methods works like this:

```
const ethers = require('ethers');
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443');

const contract = new ethers.Contract(address, [
    'function getMultiplier(uint256 _from, uint256 _to) public view returns (uint256)',
], provider);

let works = await contract.getMultiplier(5, 10);
```

---

However, if I try accessing public property, it doesn't work. In fact, I receive error with the ABI.

```
const contract = new ethers.Contract(address, [
    'uint256 public totalAllocPoint',
    'PoolInfo[] public poolInfo'
], provider);
```

> Error: unsupported fragment (argument="value", value="uint256 public totalAllocPoint", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.2.0)

`poolInfo` is even different because it needs a parameter.

How can I read `totalAllocPoint` and `poolInfo` from the contract?

---

Shouldn't it be like something like this:

```
let x = await contract.totalAllocPoint;
let y = await contract.poolInfo(2);
```

---

In the [docs](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/getting-started/#getting-started--contracts), unfortunately it only shows how to access methods

Answer (score 25, accepted):

actually in [solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters) it's pointing that for each public member variable there will be a getter is defined automatically.
In short you'll be able to get basic type public member like this: `let x = await contract.totalAllocPoint();` you've been missing parenthesis here.

While you can get array like: `let y = await contract.poolInfo(2);` if the array length is more than 3 in this case of course.

For mapping types

```
mapping (address => mapping(uint256 => Order)) public orderByAssetId;
await contract.orderByAssetId(address, id);
```

To explain it more, if you look into ABI generated from compiling your solidity contract you should be able to see like this:

Defined contract in solidity

```
contract MasterChef {
...
  uint256 public totalAllocPoint = 0;
...
}
```

equals to ABI

```
  {
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "totalAllocPoint",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "internalType": "uint256",
        "name": "",
        "type": "uint256"
      }
    ],
    "stateMutability": "view",
    "type": "function"
  },
```

Keep on coding !

---

With Human-Readable ABI of ethers.js

```
const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, [
   'function totalAllocPoint() public view returns (uint256)'
], provider)

await contract.totalAllocPoint()
```

Comment: what if the public variable is a mapping?